# How to apply PodSecurityPolicy to non kube-system namespace resources?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm testing PodSecurityPolicy resource on non kube-system namespace resources.

First thing, I have ensured admission plugin PodSecurityPolicy is enabled by checking kube-apiserver process:

```
kube-apiserver --advertise-address=192.168.56.4 --allow-privileged=true --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction,PodSecurityPolicy --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --insecure-port=0 --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=6443 --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
```

Created PodSecurityPolicy resource with below policies:

```
[root@master manifests]# kubectl get psp -o wide
NAME                PRIV    CAPS   SELINUX    RUNASUSER   FSGROUP    SUPGROUP   READONLYROOTFS   VOLUMES
podsecplcy          false          RunAsAny   RunAsAny    RunAsAny   RunAsAny   true
```

Created clusterrole and clusterrolebinding as below:

```
[root@master manifests]# kubectl describe clusterrole non-priv-role
Name:         non-priv-role
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources                   Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                   -----------------  --------------  -----
  podsecuritypolicies.policy  []                 [podsecplcy]    [list get watch]
```

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl describe clusterrolebinding psprb
Name:         psprb
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  non-priv-role
Subjects:
  Kind            Name     Namespace
  ----            ----     ---------
  ServiceAccount  default  default
[root@master ~]#
```

Below is the pod manifest which i used to create pod:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: pod-privileged
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: main
        image: alpine
        command: ["/bin/sleep", "999999"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
```

I expected that it should not allow to create privileged pod on default namespace.

Actually pod created and running fine:

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl get po
NAME                     READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
pod-privileged           1/1     Running                      0          17s
```

Do I Need to create users or groups and assign this clusterrolebinding to check or it will work since we have assigned this clusterrolebinding to default namespace and default service account?

Also how to check what is the current role and privileges what we have?

Please find the kubernetes version and podsecplcy yaml file details

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl get no
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
master.k8s   Ready    master   5d1h    v1.16.2
node1.k8s    Ready    <none>   5d      v1.16.3
node2.k8s    Ready    <none>   4d22h   v1.16.3
[root@master ~]#

[root@master ~]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.56.4:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.56.4:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
[root@master ~]#


apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"policy/v1beta1","kind":"PodSecurityPolicy","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"podsecplcy"},"spec":{"allowPrivilegeEscalation":false,"fsGroup":{"rule":"RunAsAny"},"hostIPC":false,"hostNetwork":false,"hostPID":false,"hostPorts":[{"max":30000,"min":10000}],"privileged":false,"readOnlyRootFilesystem":true,"runAsUser":{"rule":"RunAsAny"},"seLinux":{"rule":"RunAsAny"},"supplementalGroups":{"rule":"RunAsAny"},"volumes":["*"]}}
  creationTimestamp: "2019-11-23T21:31:36Z"
  name: podsecplcy
  resourceVersion: "626637"
  selfLink: /apis/policy/v1beta1/podsecuritypolicies/podsecplcy
  uid: f3316992-0dc7-4c19-852b-57e5babc451f
spec:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
  hostPorts:
  - max: 30000
    min: 10000
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
  volumes:
  - '*'
```

Comment: Please tell more about your env. BareMetal, Minikube, Kubeadm or On-Perm (some cloud providers didnt support `psp`), what version of Kubernetes was used? Provide output of `kubectl get psp <pod-security-policy-name> -o yaml`

Comment: @PjoterS - Its kubeadm.added the other required details in main question details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here How i have validated the podSecurityPolicy podsecplcy

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl get psp
NAME                PRIV    CAPS   SELINUX    RUNASUSER          FSGROUP     SUPGROUP    READONLYROOTFS   VOLUMES
podsecplcy          false          RunAsAny   RunAsAny           RunAsAny    RunAsAny    true             *
```

**Question:**
Even though we created podsecuritypolicy podsecplcy and added to clusterrole non-priv-role and assigned the same to clusterrolebinding psprb,we were able to create privileged pod without error.but expected it should throw error

**Solution:**
Whenever we are trying to submit privilege pod manifest yaml,we are not mentioning as which user or which group or which service account we want to create the pod.Since,I have installed k8s cluster using kubeadm as root,whenever i'm login as root in master node ,my role is cluster-admin and i'm able to submit privilege pod manifest yaml file since my role cluster-admin has full privileges.

So now how to test it as other user or group or service account wwhich we are going to restrict to create privileged pod?

if we are is master node as cluster-admin,then we have to submit kubectl create  command as below for testing podsecuritypolicy.

To check where we are able to create privileged pod as particular service account then

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl create -f kubia-priv-pod.yml   --as=system:serviceaccount:foo:default -n foo
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "kubia-priv-pod.yml": pods "pod-privileged" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value: true: Privileged containers are not allowed]
[root@master ~]#
[root@master ~]# kubectl create -f kubia-priv-pod.yml --as=system:serviceaccount:default:default
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "kubia-priv-pod.yml": pods "pod-privileged" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value: true: Privileged containers are not allowed]
[root@master ~]#
```

To check where we are able to create privileged pod as a combination of service account and group then

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl create -f kubia-priv-pod.yml  --as-group=system:authenticated --as=system:serviceaccount:default:default
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "kubia-priv-pod.yml": pods "pod-privileged" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value: true: Privileged containers are not allowed]
[root@master ~]#
```

To ensure whether we are able to create priv pod as cluster admin group then

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl get clusterrolebindings -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{range .subjects}}{{.kind}}-{{.name}} {{end}} {{" - "}} {{.metadata.name}} {{"\n"}}{{end}}' | grep "^Group-system:masters"
Group-system:masters   -  cluster-admin
[root@master ~]#

[root@master ~]# kubectl create -f kubia-priv-pod.yml  --as-group=system:masters --as=system:serviceaccount:default:default
pod/pod-privileged created
[root@master ~]#
```

**Additional Note:**
If we want to apply this restricted clusterrolebinding to only specific group or user or service account then we have to create as below

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding psprb --clusterrole=non-priv-role --user=jaya_vkl@yahoo.co.in
kubectl create clusterrolebinding psprbgrp --clusterrole=non-priv-role --group=system:authenticated
kubectl create clusterrolebinding psprbsa --clusterrole=non-priv-role --serviceaccount=default:default
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't prevented privilege escalation, so I will suggest that you set the directive below.
`allowPrivilegeEscalation: false`

Comment: no luck.I have added allowPrivilegeEscalation: false to psp and tried to delete and rerun the pod manifest.Still it is creating the pod